# How to Get Theme Color for Custom Theme?

Tags: android, button, colors, styles, themes

I want to get the colorAccent color of a button theme I defined in my app. I have created a custom button class. However, if I use

```
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(typedValue.data, new int[] { 
R.attr.colorAccent });
int color = a.getColor(0, 0);
```

I get the app's default colorAccent rather than the one I've defined for my button. How can I get the color of the button's theme?

Comment: I assume that, you are using activity's or root view's context. Can you try with button's context? `button.context.obtainStyledAttributes(typedValue.data, new int[] { 
R.attr.colorAccent });`

Comment: Actually, I was using the button's context, I'm just in the button class at the moment so it's still called "context"

Answer (score 0):

The fix took a while to figure out, and it's actually two-fold:

First in the custom theme, I have to use just `colorAccent` rather than `android:colorAccent` or else it confuses the program as to whether I'm defining a local or application-level value.

Once I fixed that problem, the following code variant works. (Instead of using `typedValue.data` which seems to belong to the application, I use `attrs`, which actually belongs to the button and is passed in through the constructor).

```
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, new int[] {R.attr.colorAccent});
```